# Is there a way to access Maven cmd line options from within Mojo?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Running the following command `mvn -U clean install` is there a way to check `-U` from within my custom `Mojo`?

I checked available items in `AbstractMojo.getPluginContext()` but didn't find anything for command line.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible get the information via the MavenSession:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true)
private MavenSession session;


public void execute() {
  ...
  if (session.getRequest().isNoSnapshotUpdates()) {
   ...
  }
}
```

But I would ask why do you need such information within a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @khmarbaise! 

I would like to use this flag to affect logic in my plugin and don't want to introduce new props (with almost the same meaning).

Comment: What kind of logic? That only for dependency resolution which is done by Maven core and not by plugins? so I don't understand what kind of problem/purpose this could be?

Comment: The plugin does compilation for a custom language which is not handled by Maven directly but has similar steps (source detection, compilation, dependency resolution etc)

Comment: If you have dependency resolution than the question why even using Mvaen? It does dependency resolution and much more on it's own.. Can you give more details maybe you are going the wrong path? which language?